# Is Internet Explorer 11 mode available in the new Microsoft Edge for Mac browser?

Tags: web-browser, microsoft, internet-explorer

Microsoft announced several weeks ago that it was abandoning its proprietary rendering engine for Edge and replacing it with Chromium. More recently (May 2019), it announced that it is making this [new version of the browser available for the Mac](https://appleinsider.com/articles/19/05/07/early-dev-builds-go-live-for-microsofts-edge-for-mac).

One of the key things that was announced as part of the release (at least for Windows) is that it would integrate the Internet Explorer 11 rendering engine so that users that *have to* use IE11 would not have to launch a separate browser.

My question is, is this IE11 feature only available on Windows or is it also being made available in the Mac version?

Comment: IDK, but it seems doubtful since that would be a significant porting effort of code that is on life support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Microsoft Edge team confirmed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/c094uf/hi_reddit_were_the_team_behind_microsoft_edge_and/er2v37l?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) that IE Mode is only going to be supported on Windows:

> IE mode will be supported where IE11 is currently supported so yes, it is Windows specific. Thanks!